# nested foreach loop is not working in laravel - in table data print

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, html-table

I'm trying to print the data in a table format if its available in the given date range then print as "P-Present" or "A-Absent"
But Its not prinitng the data the way I wanted. I'm cluless what can be done as I cant alter the array format of data.

Array data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 39
            [asset_id] => 1
            [description] => PA25
            [created_at] => 2017-08-17 08:13:11
            [updated_at] => 2019-02-11 11:48:39
            [status] => 1
            [cost_code] => P0005
            [weight] => 0.00
            [deleted_at] => 
            [active_from] => 2019-01-21
            [inactive_from] => 0000-00-00
            [asset] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Mini Paver
                    [default_rate] => 
                    [tax_id] => 1
                    [nominal_code] => 00001
                    [created_at] => 2017-07-24 20:35:55
                    [updated_at] => 2018-09-06 17:53:08
                    [status] => 1
                    [weekday_am] => 260
                    [weekday_pm] => 260
                    [weekend_am] => 260
                    [weekend_pm] => 260
                    [group_id] => 1
                    [cost_weekday_am] => 200
                    [cost_weekend_am] => 200
                    [cost_weekend_pm] => 200
                    [cost_weekday_pm] => 200
                    [project_code] => 
                    [manufacturer] => 
                    [model] => 
                    [purchase_date] => 1970-01-01
                    [warranty_expiry] => 
                    [mot_due] => 
                    [group] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => Pavers
                            [status] => 1
                            [created_at] => 2017-07-13 16:45:42
                            [updated_at] => 2017-07-13 16:45:42
                        )

                )

            [asset_id_allocations] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 16541
                            [job_id] => 9623
                            [job_details_id] => 27430
                            [asset_types_id] => 39
                            [date] => 2019-01-14
                            [shift] => AM
                            [created_at] => 2019-01-11 16:33:51
                            [updated_at] => 2019-01-11 16:33:51
                            [supplier_id] => 0
                            [asset_types] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 39
                                    [asset_id] => 1
                                    [description] => PA25
                                    [created_at] => 2017-08-17 08:13:11
                                    [updated_at] => 2019-02-11 11:48:39
                                    [status] => 1
                                    [cost_code] => P0005
                                    [weight] => 0.00
                                    [deleted_at] => 
                                    [active_from] => 2019-01-21
                                    [inactive_from] => 0000-00-00
                                )

                            [job_details] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 27430
                                    [asset_id] => 1
                                    [job_id] => 9623
                                    [qty] => 1
                                    [est_start_date] => 2019-01-08
                                    [days] => 
                                    [est_off_date] => 2019-01-14
                                    [rate] => 1300
                                    [row_total] => 1300
                                    [extra] => 0
                                    [assigned_asset] => 1
                                    [status] => 
                                    [comments] => 
                                    [created_at] => 2019-01-04 15:44:55
                                    [updated_at] => 2019-01-17 19:33:51
                                    [bundle_id] => 
                                    [bundle_code] => 
                                    [week_count] => 5
                                    [nonweek_count] => 
                                    [week_rate] => 260
                                    [nonweek_rate] => 260
                                    [week_total] => 260
                                    [nonweek_total] => 260
                                    [cost_only] => 0
                                    [switcher] => T
                                    [jobs] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 9623
                                            [enquiry_date] => 2018-12-20
                                            [customer_id] => 8
                                            [customer_name] => C R MacDonald Ltd
                                            [site_address] => 1750
                                            [enquiry_contact] => 484
                                            [customer_ref] => 074993
                                            [appl_payment] => 0
                                            [total_net] => 1690
                                            [total_vat] => 338
                                            [total_gross] => 2028
                                            [job_notes] => Delivery F6     -      Collection F3
                                            [invoice_Date] => 2019-01-17
                                            [invoice_no] => H9578
                                            [invoice_notes] => 
                                            [reminder_date] => 
                                            [reminder_notes] => 
                                            [status] => Archived
                                            [created_at] => 2018-12-20 19:23:25
                                            [updated_at] => 2019-01-18 16:15:57
                                            [taxcode] => 1
                                            [shift] => AM
                                            [weekend] => 0
                                            [supply_lay] => 0
                                            [profit_loss] => 
                                            [paid] => 0
                                            [job_cancel_option] => 
                                            [job_cancel_text] => 
                                            [shift_time] => 07:30
                                            [query_date] => 
                                            [query_notes] => 
                                            [cost_only] => 0
                                            [order_value] => 
                                            [credit_net] => 0
                                            [discount_total] => 0
                                            [site_contact] => 411
                                            [latitude] => 
                                            [longitude] => 
                                            [d_a] => 0
                                            [service_charge] => 0
                                            [service_charge_amount] => 0
                                            [utilisation_sheet] => 0
                                            [end_time] => 15:30
                                            [user_id] => 26
                                            [customer_sites] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 1750
                                                    [customer_id] => 8
                                                    [address1] => Poplars Farm 
                                                    [address2] => Forshaw Heath Road 
                                                    [address3] => Earlswood 
                                                    [town] => Solihull 
                                                    [area] =>  
                                                    [postcode] => B94 5JX 
                                                    [created_at] => 2019-01-04 15:42:49
                                                    [updated_at] => 2019-01-08 15:02:39
                                                    [custom_transport] => 0
                                                    [customer] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 8
                                                            [customer_code] => 1094
                                                            [customer_name] => C R MacDonald Ltd
                                                            [address1] => 27 Heming Road
                                                            [address2] => Washford Industrial Estate
                                                            [address3] => 
                                                            [town] => Redditch
                                                            [area] => Worcestershire
                                                            [postcode] => B98 0DH
                                                            [phone] => 01527 518998
                                                            [price_id] => 4
                                                            [appl_payment] => 0
                                                            [created_at] => 2018-01-16 13:38:47
                                                            [updated_at] => 2019-01-21 21:57:03
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [pay_up_front] => 0
                                                            [contact_method] => Email
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 16875
                            [job_id] => 9780
                            [job_details_id] => 28423
                            [asset_types_id] => 39
                            [date] => 2019-01-17
                            [shift] => PM
                            [created_at] => 2019-01-17 18:13:07
                            [updated_at] => 2019-01-17 18:13:07
                            [supplier_id] => 0
                            [asset_types] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 39
                                    [asset_id] => 1
                                    [description] => PA25
                                    [created_at] => 2017-08-17 08:13:11
                                    [updated_at] => 2019-02-11 11:48:39
                                    [status] => 1
                                    [cost_code] => P0005
                                    [weight] => 0.00
                                    [deleted_at] => 
                                    [active_from] => 2019-01-21
                                    [inactive_from] => 0000-00-00
                                )

                            [job_details] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 28423
                                    [asset_id] => 1
                                    [job_id] => 9780
                                    [qty] => 1
                                    [est_start_date] => 2019-01-17
                                    [days] => 
                                    [est_off_date] => 2019-01-17
                                    [rate] => 300
                                    [row_total] => 300
                                    [extra] => 0
                                    [assigned_asset] => 1
                                    [status] => 
                                    [comments] => 
                                    [created_at] => 2019-01-17 18:12:10
                                    [updated_at] => 2019-01-22 21:15:20
                                    [bundle_id] => 
                                    [bundle_code] => 
                                    [week_count] => 1
                                    [nonweek_count] => 
                                    [week_rate] => 300
                                    [nonweek_rate] => 300
                                    [week_total] => 300
                                    [nonweek_total] => 300
                                    [cost_only] => 0
                                    [switcher] => T
                                    [jobs] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 9780
                                            [enquiry_date] => 2019-01-17
                                            [customer_id] => 15
                                            [customer_name] => Eurovia - Surfacing (5054)
                                            [site_address] => 1825
                                            [enquiry_contact] => 27
                                            [customer_ref] => 4240610480
                                            [appl_payment] => 0
                                            [total_net] => 1171.85
                                            [total_vat] => 234.37
                                            [total_gross] => 1406.22
                                            [job_notes] => 
                                            [invoice_Date] => 2019-01-21
                                            [invoice_no] => H9733
                                            [invoice_notes] => 
                                            [reminder_date] => 
                                            [reminder_notes] => 
                                            [status] => Locked
                                            [created_at] => 2019-01-17 18:09:14
                                            [updated_at] => 2019-01-22 21:16:12
                                            [taxcode] => 1
                                            [shift] => PM
                                            [weekend] => 0
                                            [supply_lay] => 0
                                            [profit_loss] => 
                                            [paid] => 0
                                            [job_cancel_option] => 
                                            [job_cancel_text] => 
                                            [shift_time] => 21:30
                                            [query_date] => 
                                            [query_notes] => 
                                            [cost_only] => 0
                                            [order_value] => 
                                            [credit_net] => 0
                                            [discount_total] => 0
                                            [site_contact] => 27
                                            [latitude] => 
                                            [longitude] => 
                                            [d_a] => 0
                                            [service_charge] => 0
                                            [service_charge_amount] => 0
                                            [utilisation_sheet] => 0
                                            [end_time] => 05:30
                                            [user_id] => 26
                                            [customer_sites] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 1825
                                                    [customer_id] => 15
                                                    [address1] => M5 Junction 11  
                                                    [address2] =>   Southbound
                                                    [address3] =>   
                                                    [town] =>   
                                                    [area] =>   
                                                    [postcode] =>   
                                                    [created_at] => 2019-01-17 18:08:49
                                                    [updated_at] => 2019-01-18 22:21:58
                                                    [custom_transport] => 0
                                                    [customer] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 15
                                                            [customer_code] => 1058
                                                            [customer_name] => Eurovia - Surfacing (5054)
                                                            [address1] => PO Box 724
                                                            [address2] => 
                                                            [address3] => 
                                                            [town] => Winchester
                                                            [area] => 
                                                            [postcode] => SO23 5BU
                                                            [phone] => 01992 781101
                                                            [price_id] => 2
                                                            [appl_payment] => 0
                                                            [created_at] => 2018-01-16 14:00:47
                                                            [updated_at] => 2019-01-18 22:21:58
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [pay_up_front] => 0
                                                            [contact_method] => Email
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Table code in blade:

```
<table id="card_tbl" class="table table-bordered card_tbl_main card_view"  cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3" style="width: 90px;"></th>
            @foreach($daterange as $date)
            <th colspan="2" style="width:280px;">{{ $date->format('D d M Y') }}</th>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
        <tr role="row">
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            @foreach($daterange as $date)
            <th>AM</th>
            <th>PM</th>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($asset_array as $final)
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ trim($final['asset']['group']['name']) }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ trim($final['asset']['name']) }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ trim($final['description']) }}
            </td>
            @foreach($daterange as $day)
            <td>
                @if(count($final['asset_id_allocations']) > 0)
                    @foreach($final['asset_id_allocations'] as $allocation)
                        @if($allocation['date'] == $day->format('Y-m-d') && $allocation['job_details']['jobs']['shift'] == "AM")

                            P
                        @else
                            A
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                @else
                    A
                @endif
            </td>
            <td>
                @if(count($final['asset_id_allocations']) > 0)
                    @foreach($final['asset_id_allocations'] as $allocation)
                        @if($allocation['date'] == $day->format('Y-m-d') && $allocation['job_details']['jobs']['shift'] == "PM")

                            P
                        @else
                            A
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                @else
                    A
                @endif
            </td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the output that I'm getting:

[image]

But I want the output to be like below format:
[image]

Any suggestions please.

This is the code gives me wrong output:
Here  I have the date range for 5 days which means 10 columns but i have `asset_id_allocations` output for only two dates that one is for `AM` another is `PM` for another date .

```
@foreach($daterange as $day)
            <td>
                @if(count($final['asset_id_allocations']) > 0)
                    @foreach($final['asset_id_allocations'] as $allocation)
                        @if($allocation['date'] == $day->format('Y-m-d') && $allocation['job_details']['jobs']['shift'] == "AM")

                            P
                        @else
                            A
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                @else
                    A
                @endif
            </td>
            <td>
                @if(count($final['asset_id_allocations']) > 0)
                    @foreach($final['asset_id_allocations'] as $allocation)
                        @if($allocation['date'] == $day->format('Y-m-d') && $allocation['job_details']['jobs']['shift'] == "PM")

                            P
                        @else
                            A
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                @else
                    A
                @endif
            </td>
            @endforeach
```

Comment: Could you please cut down your code to the exact place you are having issues with rather than the whole code?

Comment: @ka_lin : Could you please check I have added the code below.

Comment: looks like it has something todo with your foreach loop, not going to dive into the array but try to print the result of your if statement and how often it runs.

Comment: @mrQubeMaster: `$daterange foreach` will run 10  times to print the date with `AM` and `PM`. Inside this foreach loop i need to check `asset_id_allocations` is having the date which is there in the given range with shift. My result `asset_id_allocations` is having two rows. I know the problem but i don't know how to fix this :(

Comment: @06011991 could you provide the array as json data with `JSON.stringify($array);` so i can easily import it into my project and do some testing

Answer (score 0):

Please check this portion :

```
<td>
    **@if(count($final['asset_id_allocations']) > 0)
        @foreach($final['asset_id_allocations'] as $allocation)**
            @if($allocation['date'] == $day->format('Y-m-d') && $allocation['job_details']['jobs']['shift'] == "AM")
                P
            @else
                A
            @endif
        @endforeach
    @else
        A
    @endif
</td>
```

If the count is more than 1 it will print inside the same "td" according to your code.

Comment: Yeah this is the portion I need to fix. But how do I do that? :(

Comment: make the if statement more strict. looks to be to generale, that is why it is calling multiple times

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not getting. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: Check the count. Do you need to print for all cases? Then Keep the td inside the loop else print once and break. Depends on the requirement which is not very clear and we can't see the full array data either.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting you right, try this one,

```
        @foreach($daterange as $day)
                    <td>
                        @if(count($final['asset_id_allocations']) > 0)
                            @foreach($final['asset_id_allocations'] as $allocation)
                                @if($allocation['date'] == $day->format('Y-m-d') && $allocation['job_details']['jobs']['shift'] == "AM")

                                    P
                                    @break
                                @else
                                    A
                                    @break
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                        @else
                            A
                        @endif
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if(count($final['asset_id_allocations']) > 0)
                            @foreach($final['asset_id_allocations'] as $allocation)
                                @if($allocation['date'] == $day->format('Y-m-d') && $allocation['job_details']['jobs']['shift'] == "PM")

                                   A
                                  @break
                                @else
                                    P
                                  @break
                                @endif
                                @endforeach
                        @else
                            A
                        @endif
                    </td>
                    @endforeach
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188867/discussion-between-06011991-and-maulik-shah).